# create file from solution explorer "missing file"

Tags: c#, file, svn, visual-studio-2013

A small but very annoying issue I have:

In our current working way, all .config files are excluded from source control. Also a .tmpl file with the .config content is included in the source. So when I check out a project from source control I end up with:

```
[Triangle]Log4Net.config
Log4Net.Config.templ
```

In my solution explorer. Clicking on the Log4Net.config file (predictably) gives the error, "The item 'Log4Net.config' does not exist in the project directory. It may have been moved, renamed or deleted." Fair enough.

I am looking for a way to "make" that file, like for eg. right click force open, that will open a new empty editor window where I can paste in the content. (I can easily just copy it from the .tmpl file).

Anything like a plugin, or a keyboard shortcut or similar would be what I'm looking for.

Update: To clarify, the .sln/.csproj file(s) are checked in referencing the files. I check this out and open in visual studio. I see the yellow triangle moaning about missing files. Now I need to recreate these files, and I would like to use VS to do so...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, though I'll try to reply. As I know it's better to keep all solution related files on the source control. So, you have to add all those files and if you don't want to track changes than you do this: select file you need to exclude from tracking changes in Solution Explorer, and choose File -> Source Control -> Exclude file from Source Control.

Comment: no no, you misunderstood.. I'm dealing with the consequences of this policy,,  The file is already excluded and the solution is checked in referencing the file. When a new developer (me) comes along and checks out the solution, all these files are "missing". I need to recreate them, and I'm looking for a way within visual studio to do so..

Comment: I have not faced issues like that, but as a last resort you always can use pre-built event in order to copy the file you want into the target directory.

Comment: can you give some more detail on this? is it something i can do from a right click on the missing file?

Comment: No, pre-build events allow you to execute commands every time you build your project. You can execute there a simple .bat file which will "recreate or make" the file you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: The answer is no you cant do this with VS out of the box. The way to do it otherwise would be to simply read the proj (its just an xml file) and compare file system with proj included entries, creating the missing files when not present on file system. That said you're doing it wrong. Your policies need to change.

Comment: I get that it's not out the box functionality, but surely there must be a plugin or something that allows me to create a missing file from the solution explorer?

Comment: Maybe but your policies are so unusual that I doubt its a problem anyone has needed/bothered to solve by writing a plugin that they then have to maintain. Why cant you just delete/recreate?

Comment: I can, and do the following: minimise visual studio, open notepad, paste the content, save as, then nav to the location and type the file name, and save. Was hoping there was a faster way